# White screen on one monitor after logon... how to fix?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia

Today I have been having major issues....

I was running Unity2D even though I was choosing Ubuntu in the cog menu (was trying to get transparent panels). This seemed to be caused by my graphics drivers.

After reinstalling my nvida proprietary drivers, I now have Unity3D, but one of my screens shows up as white.

The screen is totally blank (white) and when moving the mouse into it shows a black X icon instead of the usual mouse pointer.

Running the script from this [blog](http://dp.nonoo.hu/revodrive-3-gtx560ti-on-ubuntu/) make the wallpaper show up, but I still cannot use the desktop on that screen. I can't drag windows there but can move mouse onto it. I'm not sure where to run the scripts so I just run them from a terminal window... maybe they need running sooner....

My Hardware:

- Asus P5Q Pro
- Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600 @ 2.40GHz x4
- GeForce 9600GT
- 32-bit OS - Ubuntu 11.10
- 4x 1GB DDR2 RAM Modules
- Latest NVIDIA drivers from their website

Comment: I can configure either monitor to work (as primary) and the other will show the white screen with the black X mouse icon when I move the mouse into that screen. Can't drag windows there either. When I first log in it shows the correct wallpaper before going to a white screen. Any ideas????

Comment: I have done a re-install and I'm still stuck with the White Screen issue. Apparently this is because a Window Manager hasn't started on that screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my problem was related to my understanding of setting up multiple monitors.

I took it that TwinView meant that it would 'mirror' the display so was trying to use seperate X windows.

Eventually worked this one out!